# PHP - How to change font size of HTML table?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm generating table in a foreach loop

```
echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$monthName."</td>";   
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$id."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$total."</td>"  

echo "</tr>";
```

I need to increase font size of the table, but i'm not sure how. Does the html table has attribute to set font size or I should use CSS ?

Comment: just use css for the alignment, background color, and font size, please

Comment: CSS really is your best bet. `table { font-size: 10px; }`. Problem solved.

Comment: @ObsidianAge has the right answer. Define it in a CSS block, so that it applies to the table (can even 'class' it). Doing inline for every cell in every row is needless cruft when a proper define covers them all.

Answer (score 2):

Just use font style css in style attribute :

```
echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr' style='font-size:10px'>".$monthName."</td>";   
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$bgclr' style='font-size:10px'>".$id."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$bgclr' style='font-size:10px'>".$total."</td>"  

echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

use the html styling on the echoed elements. For example `echo '<table style="font-size: 100px">';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define font size in one variable and then use in inline as below code:

```
foreach{
    $fontsize = 'font-size: '.((isset(FONT_SIZE_IN_FOREACH))?FONT_SIZE_IN_FOREACH:12);
echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='$bgclr' style='$fontsize'>".$monthName."</td>";   
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$id."</td>";    
    echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$bgclr'>".$total."</td>"  

echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to the table and write css for that class.

HTML:

```
<table class='fontsize'>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
.fontsize {
   font-size:16px;
 }
```